# How do I sort not the elements of an array, but it's indexes?

Tags: c++

So I have an array like this:

```
int array[]={2, 4, 3, 1};
```

I want to sort this in descending order, but get the original indexes, like this: 
    {1, 2, 0, 3}
How do I solve this so it works with an array of any size?
Also, is there a solution that doesn't need C++11?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you elaborate the question?

Comment: It is unclear what the problem is.

Comment: What do you really want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a tricky and easy workaround: First you have an unsorted array so create an array of indexes `{0, 1, 2, 3}` then use loops to sort the array of values and at the same time swap the elements of array of indexes according to the array of values:

```
int array[] = {2, 4, 3, 1};
int indexes[] = {0, 1, 2, 3};

for(int i(0); i < 4; i++){
    for(int j(i + 1); j < 4; j++){
        if(array[i] < array[j]){

            //sorting values
            array[i] ^= array[j];
            array[j] ^= array[i];
            array[i] ^= array[j];

            // sorting indexes
            indexes[i] ^= indexes[j];
            indexes[j] ^= indexes[i];
            indexes[i] ^= indexes[j];
        }
    }
}

cout << endl;
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    cout << array[i] << ", ";
cout << endl;

for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    cout << indexes[i] << ", ";
```

I used `xor` to sort the arrays however you can use a temporary variable:

```
int tmp = array[i]; 
array[i] = array[j];
array[j] = tmp;

tmp = indexes[i];
indexes[i] = indexes[j];
indexes[j] = tmp;
```

The output:

```
4, 3, 2, 1,
1, 2, 0, 3,
```

Answer (score 5):

I would go for something like this:

```
std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> temp ;
int idx = 0 ;
for (auto x : array)
    temp.push_back(std::make_pair(x, idx++)) ;
std::sort(temp.begin(), temp.end()) ;
```

You can easily get rid of the range for (the only C++11 construct used here). There is no need to define a comparison for std::pair, the default one is OK.

Comment: Not so OK, they want "descending order".

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you want to get a soted list of indices. One solution is to create an unordered list of indices of all elements and sort it.

```
int array[] = {2, 4, 3, 1};
int indices[] = {0, 1, 2, 3};

std::sort(indices, indices + 4, [&](int a, int b) {
    return array[b] < array[a];
});
```

Since you asked for a non-C++11-way, you can work around the lambda expression as shown below:

```
int array[] = {2, 4, 3, 1};
int indices[] = {0, 1, 2, 3};

struct {
    int *array;
    bool operator()(int a, int b) const
    {
        return this->array[b] < this->array[a];
    }
} customLess = {array};

std::sort(indices, indices + 4, customLess);
```

Both implementations will sort the values of `indices` but *not* `array` itself. The result would look as shown below:

```
array == {2, 4, 3, 1}
indices == {1, 2, 0, 3}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to save the initial index somewhere.
One solution would be with an struct. Somewhat like this:

```
struct IndexInt
{
    int index;
    int value;

} typename IndexInt_t

IndexInt_t array[]={{1,2}, {2,4}, {3,3}, {4,1}};
```

Now you can sort after `array[i].value` and access the origin index via `array[i].index`.